# Half of Earth with most landmass

Tags: spatial-statistics, geography, surface

About 71% of the Earth's surface is covered with water and the remaining 29% is landmass[*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth). If you could theoretically cut the planet in half, with the objective of producing a half with the most landmass possible (and another with the most water possible), where would the cut be? More specifically, where would the centers (in the surface) of both halves be located?

Comment: I wonder if this type of question is more suited for [EarthScienceStackExchange](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) :)

Comment: This is easy enough to model using GIS, but as written, this is more of a geography trivial question.  GIS SE is about focused *GIS* questions.

Comment: @Joseph I actually asked there first, but their answers weren't precise at all. http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/8226/6180

Comment: @Gabe12 - Glad to see you did! But you did only ask it 12 hours ago (as of this comment). You should probably wait atleast a day to see if others answer your question. Also, [cross posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) is discouraged in Stack Exchange =)

Comment: If you're not willing to do the work to identify the location identified by that perfectly reasonable answer, why would you expect us to do it for you?

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search yielded [this result](https://books.google.com/books?id=NBI9DAAAQBAJ&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=how%20to%20cut%20the%20earth%20in%20half%20by%20landmass&source=bl&ots=pqUPeAeKVB&sig=x0ug4ZEi8tNhowySFq72V-qQXCI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRzNuKmLnNAhUIE1IKHQWTBSsQ6AEIWDAI#v=onepage&q=how%20to%20cut%20the%20earth%20in%20half%20by%20landmass&f=false) which states in the paragraph before "Continents and Oceans" that *'this land hemisphere is centered on Western Europe.'* You could validate this and get the precise location with functions in PostGIS by finding the centroid of a polygon (landmass).  Then you can do some math to find the cut line based on the centroid.